# How to bind event-handler when compile HTML snippet dynamically in AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, openlayers, angularjs-compile

I'm using the OpenLayers with AngularJS, everything goes well until I was starting touch the popup functionality eventually.

I know how to use `$compile` service to make the dynamic content shows up in the popup by:

```
$scope.data = {
    text: "Dynamic content"
};

var template = "<div><span>{{data.text}}</span></div>";

$scope.showPopup = function() {
    var content = $compile(template)($scope);

    var lonlat = "-5694.06868525478, 6708925.0877411375";
    $timeout(function() {
        var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("popup",
            OpenLayers.LonLat.fromString(lonlat),
            null,
            content.html(),
            null,
            true
        );

        map.addPopup(popup);
    }, 0);
};
```

but I was struggling with the event handler now, if I change the `template` to(note the input  and `ng-click` after the span):

```
var template = "<div><span>{{data.text}}</span><input type='button' ng-click='func()' value='click me'/></div>";
```

and define the event handler in `$scope`:

```
$scope.func = function() {
    console.log("Hello, world");
};
```

but the event cannot be triggered. I highly doubt that using the `content.html()` will lose some important information which angularjs cares about. When I tried the following code:

```
    var template = "<div><span>{{data.text}}</span><input type='button' ng-click='func()' value='click me'/></div>";
    var content = $compile(template)($scope);
    angular.element("#footer").append(content);
```

this snippet works perfectly as expected(ng-click works here as well). The only difference between those two usage is: `content` and `content.html()`.

But I cannot use `content` given the `OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud` expects an static html content string.

Any ideas about this? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe it's not about the compile itself, the main thing here is about `content` and `content.html()`. How can I get the content of an element include the element itself. `content.html()` doesn't work(it returns only the content of an element).

Answer (score 5):

I have met with the same problem and spent 3 days to find the solution. Finally I found out that the solution is to call the $compile function after the popup is added to the map. See this fiddle.
[Openlayers with Angularjs](http://jsfiddle.net/tianhai/R4W5R/)

```
var template = "<div><span>{{halo}}</span><button ng-click='call()'>call</button></div>";
var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("popup", new OpenLayers.LonLat(103.83641, 1.35578), null, template, null, true);
map.addPopup(popup);
var pp = angular.element(document.querySelector('#popup'));
$compile(pp)($scope);
```

After the popup is added to the map, a new dom is created. Using Angularjs's jqlite, we can get the dom and compile it against the scope to make it bind to the method you need to call.

Answer (score 0):

I use leaflet

```
var map = L.map('div-map');                    
// ...
```

Create your Scope object

```
var newScope = $scope.$new();

newScope.object = someObject;

newScope.myfunction = function(){ console.log("Testing")}
```

Your html String

```
var html =  
'<div><p><strong>ID : </strong>{{object.userId}}</p>'+
'<p><strong>Name : </strong>{{object.firstName}} {{object.lastName}}</p>'+
'<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="myfunction()">Call My Function</button></div>';
```

Parse HTML into DOM element

```
var template = angular.element(html);
```

Compile the template

```
var linkFn = $compile(template);
```

Link the compiled template with the scope.

```
var element = linkFn(newScope);

var marker = L.marker(
   [ object.latitude, object.longitude],
   {icon: -someIcon-}
)
.bindPopup( element[0]);

map.addLayer(marker);
```

Don't forget to inject ($compile) into your code.